# StencilJS trying to set component's internal input tag state according to Prop input

Tags: stenciljs

I'm building a custom `input` tag with `stenciljs` and I dont understand how to set the `input`s `disabled` or `readonly` state. I'm passing the property to the component from the parent as an `enum` with 3 properties as follows:

```
enum INPUT_STATE {
  DISABLED = "disabled",
  READONLY = "readonly",
  DEFAULT = ""
}
```

And the component looks as follows:

```
export class InputFields {

  @Prop() inputState: INPUT_STATE;

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="status">
        <input type="text" {...INPUT_STATE[this.inputState]}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is to set the passed property on the `input`, be it `disabled` or `readonly` and an empty string for default state. How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: What do you get from `console.log({...INPUT_STATE[this.inputState]})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INPUT_STATE` is an enum. The INPUT_STATE values are strings, so `INPUT_STATE[this.inputState]` is a string not an object. Strings don't map directly to jsx attributes - you would have to set explicitly:

```
<input type="text" disabled={this.inputState === INPUT_STATE.DISABLED}/>
```

By using a watch , you can move the logic out of the JSX:

```
private inputStateAttr = {};
  
@Prop() inputState: INPUT_STATE;
@Watch('inputState')
handleInputStateChange(value: INPUT_STATE) {
  this.inputStateAttr = {
    disabled: INPUT_STATE.DISABLED === value,
    readonly: INPUT_STATE.READONLY === value
  };
}

render() {
  return (
    <div class="status">
      <input type="text" {...this.inputStateAttr}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: that work as expected. thanks. is there a way of achieving this without writing two separated lines for `disabled` and `readOnly`? some generic syntax?

Comment: Sort of - you still need to check the value of the property against the enum, but you can move it out of the JSX. See updated answer.